# How to make part of a slice (in MATLAB slice function) transparent according to the values of the 3D data matrix?

Tags: matlab

I want to display 30 slices of a 3D matrix. I'm using the MATLAB slice command. My data has circular symmetry and it's important part is located near the axis of symmetry. When I use the slice command the zero part of my data obsure the important data. See The figure below, which was created by the attached code. I want to make the unimportant part of each slice (the blue regions) completely transparant. How can I do that?

The code after modification according to Suever answer: (Still does not work!)

What seems to be the problem ???  -Answer:  I found out that I had also to set the FaceAlpha property to 'interp'

```
function  presentFig4_ver3
close all; clc; 
load('img3D_shrinked.mat' , 'im3' , 'y_n_mm' , 'xticksVec_mm')

[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(y_n_mm,y_n_mm,xticksVec_mm);        
slices=xticksVec_mm; %= 0.23:0.1:(0.23+((30-1)*0.1));  %This is the same as xticksVec_mm 

len_slices=length(slices);
h=zeros(1,len_slices);

for ind=1:len_slices        
    h(ind)=slice(X,Y,Z, im3, [],[],[slices(ind)]);
    set(h(ind),'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','interp','AlphaData',(im3>0.001)*0.1);    
    set(gca,'ZDir','reverse')
    hold on
end
end   % of function
```

[image: Result after code modification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting the same alpha value for an entire slice to be 0.5 using `alpha`, you'll want to specify the [`AlphaData` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartsurface-properties.html#property_alphadata) which will specify a transparency value for each pixel in your input image and you will want to set `FaceAlpha` to be either `'flat'` or `'interp'`.

For example, we could use `im` as the `AlphaData`

```
set(h(ind), 'AlphaData', im, 'FaceAlpha', 'flat')
```

If instead, you want all pixels below a certain threshold to be completely transparent, you can create a logical array and use that instead.

```
set(h(ind), 'AlphaData', im > threshold, 'FaceAlpha', 'flat')
```

If you want all values greater than the threshold to be partly transparent rather than opaque, you could multiply the mask by 0.5.

```
set(h(ind), 'AlphaData', (im > threshold) * 0.5, 'FaceAlpha', 'flat')
```

Comment: Hello Suever, for some reason your solution doesn't work for me. I'll show my code in an edit of the question.

Comment: I found the problem. I needed also to set the FaceAlpha property to 'interp'.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @O.T. Oh yes, sorry about that. I had initially read your `FaceColor` being set to `interp` as being `FaceAlpha`. I have updated my answer to include `FaceAlpha`